# What is the NativeGuid in DirectoryEntry when querying via the WinNT provider?

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices

I'm writing an application which I want to work with both Active Directory and local users and groups.  I thought I could use the NativeGuid property of a DirectoryEntry as a unique identifier which was retrieved using the WinNT provider against LocalHost. However, using the following code in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) I get the same NativeGuid for both entries.  Querying Active Dirctory with the LDAP provider appears to yield unique results, but now I'm unsure.

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry localuserde = 
  new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://localhost/localuser");
localuserde.NativeGuid.Dump("localUser Guid");
    
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry adminde = 
new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://localhost/administrator");
adminde.NativeGuid.Dump("administrator Guid");
```

Can someone please explain what the NativeGuid represents when using the WinNT provider, and is there a good alternative for a uniqueId or is the SID a better choice?

*To run the above in LinqPad hit F4 and add System.DirectoryServices.dll to the list of assemblies.  Then make sure that localuser either exists or change the name to a local user on the system.  Then hit F5.*

Thanks,

Shane Holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the SID is probably your best bet in any user- and group-related scenario here. There's really no other unique identifier - especially not with the WinNT provider.

For more info on the [WinNT vs. LDAP](http://www.rlmueller.net/WinNT_LDAP.htm) discussion and for great reference Excel sheets on what properties each of those providers really expose (and what their names are), visit Richard Mueller's [Hilltop Lab](http://www.rlmueller.net/index.html). Richard is an ADSI MVP and has excellent contents for anyone interested in Active Directory and LDAP.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828036/how-to-get-user-guid-from-active-directory-using-winnt-protocol) says not to use NativeGuid.  I would use the "SID" instead.