# When using DirectoryEntry to get all children for local machine all children objects have identical GUIDs

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am using System.DirectoryServices to get all of the entries for the local machine. (non domain connected)
Like this:

```
public static List<DirectoryEntry> GetLocalMachineEntries()
{
    List<DirectoryEntry> returnValue = new List<DirectoryEntry>();
    DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);
    foreach (DirectoryEntry entry in localMachine.Children)
    {
        returnValue.Add(entry);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

However, when I actually read through each of the entries, most of the GUIDs are identical. The actual SIDs, Paths and Names are correct and match what I'd expect. To be clear, I am trying to use the object GUIDs instead of SIDs because in some rare cases SIDs can change.

So how can I get the actual GUID values for these entries?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the WinNT provider (for querying local users/groups) does not actually support the GUID property.

See answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/828082/634805